# Format fractional separator of C# decimal

Tags: formatting, decimal

I'm interacting with a 3rd party system that requires me to send it decimal numbers where s decimal **comma** must precede the fractional part. If the value has no fractional part the decimal comma must still be present.

So for example

```
decimal d = 123.45M; //needs to become 123,45
decimal d2 = 345M; //needs to become 345,
```

Is there an elegant way of formatting .net decimals for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your 3rd party system might simply be using a different Culture. You can set the [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that you want to use and formatting will do what it needs to for that culture including dates, numbers, and currency.

Example:

```
CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(culture, "{0}", 123.45M));
```

Output:

```
123,45
```

Even if you want to keep the current culture but for a given purpose override just one thing you can override them by:

```
culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
```

**Edit**: I've found no way of doing the trailing decimal separator using only the built-in numeric formatting but you might be able to find something looking through the [custom numeric format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Otherwise you may have to resort to simply testing for `d2 % 1 == 0` and manually adding the decimal separator.

Example:

```
public static string FormatWithTrailing(decimal number)
{
    // Change the following culture to the actual desired culture
    CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("fr-FR");
    return number % 1 == 0 
        ? number.ToString(culture) + culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator 
        : number.ToString(culture);
}
```

Outputs:

```
123,45
345,
```